# How to make the safe area on top and bottom of the view in WKWebView non-transparent?

Tags: swift, storyboard, wkwebview

I am doing the webview app on iOS. Using `WKWebView`. The webview shows on top some space with transparent background which I assume is safe area top bar and bottom bar.
I am getting transparent space at top. At bottom content going below the bottom safe area which is also transparent. Content at bottom should be above the safe area bottom tab or something.

How to make the safe area top bar non-transparent?
How to make the content to come above the bottom safe area position.

[image]

I want to make the top safe area to be non-transparent, maybe as white color background for the top area where time, charging of phone etc is displaying.

At bottom space also white background for the bottom tab of phone.